# Finding The Characteristic Polynomial of a Matrix With Integer Sum Coefficients.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, cayley-hamilton

Good day, I'm having a bit of trouble with this one, I'm given the matrix \begin{bmatrix}1&2&...&n\\n+1&n+2&... &2n\\...&...&...&...\\n^2-n+1&n^2-n+2&...&n^2\end{bmatrix}
And I'm asked to compute the characteristic polynomial, with the added hint that $W=<(1,1,...,1),(1,2,...,n)>$ is invariant.

I'm a bit confused by the relationship between rows, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have matrix 
$$  u v^T + n (v-u) u^T  $$
where
$$
u =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
1 \\
1 \\
... \\
1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$
v =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
2 \\
3 \\
... \\
n
\end{array}
\right)
$$
where $u \cdot v \neq 0$

We can make a basis $u,v,w_3,w_4, ..., w_n$ where all $w_i \cdot u = 0, \; $
all $w_i \cdot v = 0, \; $ and $i \neq j$ gives $w_i \cdot w_j = 0.$
It follows that all $w_i$ are eigenvectors with eigenvalue $0. \;$

We just need to find out what happens to vectors $a u + b v,$ that is
$$ \left(  u v^T + n (v-u) u^T \right) (au + bv) = ??   $$ 
and finding these final eigenvectors and eigenvalues. We know, for real $a,b,$ that the result is some $cu+dv$ with $c,d$ also real. So we expect to get two final real eigenvalues.

Using $$  E = u \cdot u = n, \; \;  F = u \cdot v = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}, \; \; G = v \cdot v = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} \; \; ,  $$
we want the eigenvalues of
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
F - n E & G - n F \\
n E & nF
\end{array}
\right)
$$
I guess the actual nonzero eigenvalues are a bit of a mess, however the characteristic polynomial comes out
$$  x^n - \left( \frac{n(n^2+1)}{2} \right) x^{n-1} -  \left( \frac{n^3(n^2-1)}{12} \right) x^{n-2} $$

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: @JuanF. If your problem has been solved, you can accept this answer by clicking on the tick mark.